# How to instantiate a FileTree in a Groovy class managed by Gradle?

Tags: groovy, gradle

I have a Gradle build script, that grew too big so I made a utility class.
In this class I want to use the Gradle fileTree (or any other Gradle class), how can I do it? 
To be clear, this is in build.gradle:

```
ext {
    utils = new Utils()
}
```

and in Utils.groovy (which is in buildSrc/src/main/groovy):

```
def chopBackgroundImage(String inPath, String outPath, int scale) {
       new File(outPath).mkdirs();
       def tree = fileTree(dir: inPath, include: '*.png') // doesnt work
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`fileTree` is a method defined on [Project](https://gradle.org/docs/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Project.html) interface so there's a need to pass `project` instance to method and import `Project` class in `Utils`. `Utils` should look like this:

```
import org.gradle.api.Project

public class Utils {
    def chopBackgroundImage(Project project, String inPath, String outPath, int scale) {
       new File(outPath).mkdirs();
       def tree = project.fileTree(dir: inPath, include: '*.png') 
    }
}
```

To make `Project` accessible in `buildSrc` modify *build.gradle* by adding the following content:

```
buildscript {
   dependencies {
      gradleApi()
   }
}
```

And - of course - because of the fact that groovy is a dynamic language `chopBackgroundImage` can be defined in the following way:

```
def chopBackgroundImage(project, inPath, outPath, scale) {
   new File(outPath).mkdirs()
   def tree = project.fileTree(dir: inPath, include: '*.png') 
}
```

No dependencies needed! ;)

Comment: Thanks, it works fine. But the buildSrc part is not working, it throws an exception, so I simply pass the project in Util's constructor argument.

Comment: almost, lowercase "S" :). btw it works without the `buildscript` block too, I just add `Utils utils = new Utils()`